# returning table.column in a SQL select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I want my sql query to return the projection as **table.column** instead of just column.

For example

```
select deal.deal_id from deal where deal.deal_id= '1';
```

What it returns is

```
DEAL_ID
-------
1
```

What I want is:

```
DEAL.DEAL_ID
------------
1
```

How can I accomplish that, **without** using **AS** or the Oracle quote operator?

Comment: Why not alias? Please put what DB are you using.

Comment: oracle db. I'd stay away from aliases if I can, too much overhead

Comment: @Yosi it's not a duplicate of that question. I know how to use AS, but don't want to use AS. I want, if possible, Oracle to fully qualify the name for me.

Comment: @fabiog:- Have you checked the answers. Both the answers dont have **AS** !! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi just rephrased the question... pls don't vote the question down just because don't know the answer!

Comment: @fabiog:- That is not my downvote! And the reason you are getting the downvotes might be because you have not clarified why you dont want to use AS or quote identifiers!

Comment: First question should be: Can I? then how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you give an alias:

```
SELECT deal.deal_id "deal.deal_id"
FROM deal 
WHERE deal.deal_id= '1';
```

**There is no way this can be done automatically.**

Comment: no AS, it should be without aliases

Comment: @fabiog: There is no AS in his answer.

Comment: same thing, I have to type it. I want oracle to fully qualify the column for me.

Comment: @fabiog - see the last sentence - it's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
select deal_id "DEAL.DEAL_ID" from deal where deal.deal_id= '1';
```

Comment: @fabiog:- Is it showing error with AS?

Comment: @fabiog:- Ok then remove the AS. Simple edit!

Comment: @fabiog: Why you can't aliases?

Comment: @Kaf:- I have no idea why OP doesnt want alias! fabiog:- You can also look for Oracle quote operator also!

Comment: @RahulTripathi oracle quote operator is basically the same thing. it requires me to do the writing

Comment: @fabiog:- The above answer doesnot have an AS. Secondly is there any particular reason you are avoiding AS ?

Comment: @fabiog:- AFAIK there is no other way by which you can achieve this :)